# Saving variable of a message in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, try-catch

i like to save my sended DM to a user in a local variable. How can I do this?
I would like to react on that message, but if I use .then() after or before the required .catch()-block, the log says "Cannot send messages to this user", without it, I can send the message..

Thank you!!

Code:

```
client.users.cache
  .get(memb.id)
  .send(emb5)
  .catch((msb) => {
    write("Error");
  })
  .then((msg) => {
    msg.react(one);
  });
```

*one* is the emoji...

Comment: Are you sure the member hasn't blocked their DMs?

Comment: Else just fetch the user before, he is certainly not in cache.

Comment: @Leau (1) I tested it myself and I don't block dm's...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) you can put the message in a variable like this:

```
const user = await client.users.fetch(mem.id); // Fetching the user
const awaitedMessage = await user.send(emb5); // Send the message to the user
awaitedMessage.react(one); // React the sent message
```

Comment: This works fine! Thank you